# Tensorflow2, Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to compute a sum of gradients (that will later be used in the network optimizer), here is the code:

```
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    log_proba = tf.math.log(0.7)
    val_acc = tf.constant(0.6)
    grad_log_proba = tape.gradient(log_proba, controller.trainable_weights)
    sum_over_choices = grad_log_proba * val_acc
```

Which gives the error:

> ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.

I looked at other posts but I could not find an answer.

Any idea?

[**UPDATE**]

Here is the entire stack trace:

> File "Controller.py", line 368, in main
>
> sum_over_choices = grad_log_proba * val_acc
>
> File
> "C:\Users\aymer.conda\envs\PythonCPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py",
> line 1155, in r_binary_op_wrapper
>
> x = ops.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=y.dtype.base_dtype, name="x")
>
> File
> "C:\Users\aymer.conda\envs\PythonCPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
> line 1499, in convert_to_tensor
>
> ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\aymer.conda\envs\PythonCPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py",
> line 338, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
>
> return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\aymer.conda\envs\PythonCPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py",
> line 263, in constant
>
> return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
>
> File
> "C:\Users\aymer.conda\envs\PythonCPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py",
> line 275, in _constant_impl
>
> return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\aymer.conda\envs\PythonCPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py",
> line 300, in _constant_eager_impl
>
> t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\aymer.conda\envs\PythonCPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py",
> line 98, in convert_to_eager_tensor
>
> return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
>
> ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type
> (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.

p.s: I already posted this one hour ago on another account but I deleted it by mistake, so here it is

Comment: Hi! Did you check similar issues yet ?       
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67860096/got-valueerror-attempt-to-convert-a-value-none-with-an-unsupported-type-cla                                                                                     Please provide a stand alone code to reproduce this issue too.