# Got ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

When I tried to run a colab notebook on 2021 June, which was created on 2020 december and ran fine I got an error. So I changed

```
baseModel = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(weights="imagenet", 
                                     include_top= False,
                                     input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))
```

to

```
baseModel = tf.keras.applications.VGG19(weights="imagenet", 
                                     include_top= False,
                                     input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
```

However when I continued to execute the notebook I got an error "ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor." in a later stage.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import math
import os

import keras
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import *
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet121
from keras.callbacks import *
from keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import matplotlib.cm as cm

from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer,LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix


import tensorflow as tf
baseModel = tf.keras.applications.VGG19(weights="imagenet", 
                                     include_top= False,
                                     input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(64, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.4)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(headModel)
model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)

model.summary()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-6695ac43a942> in <module>()
      1 headModel = baseModel.output
      2 headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4))(headModel)
----> 3 headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
      4 headModel = Dense(64, activation="relu")(headModel)
      5 headModel = Dropout(0.4)(headModel)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
     96       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
     97   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 98   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
     99 
    100 

ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.
```

Updated imports:

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import math
import os

import tensorflow as tf

import tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from tensorflow.keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet121
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import *
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import matplotlib.cm as cm

from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer,LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
```

Comment: I'm unable to reprocude the issue on Colab. Can you add all imports? Just to be sure about you don't mix `keras` and `tf.keras` imports.

Comment: Edited the question to include all the imports

Comment: You are mixing `keras` and `tf.keras`. Try to import your layers from `tf.keras.layers`.

Comment: Thx a lot it fixed the issue. Updated imports are added to the question in case someone else face the same problem again.

Comment: Also can you plz post this as an answer so i can accept the answer and give the credit you deserve

Comment: You can accept the current answer, not a problem for me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Frightera suggested, you are mixing `keras` and `tensorflow.keras` imports. Try the code with all `tensorflow.keras` imports,

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import math
import os

from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from tensorflow.keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet121
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import *
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import matplotlib.cm as cm

from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer,LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

import tensorflow as tf

baseModel = tf.keras.applications.VGG19(weights="imagenet", 
                                     include_top= False,
                                     input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(64, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.4)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(headModel)
model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)

model.summary()
```

Comment: Thx Shubham. Already did it and it worked. Also updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue with an old code.
but with a newer version of python the code was not working properly.
but i solved the issue by changing it to the latest requirments.

here is the solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68049002/15345841