# Keras flatten: ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I have the error mentioned in the title, with the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from random import shuffle
import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot

from numpy import mean
from numpy import std
from matplotlib import pyplot
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

first_branch= Input(shape=(28,28,1))
first_branch_st1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28,1))(first_branch)
first_branch_st2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(first_branch_st1)
first_branch_st3 = Flatten()(first_branch_st2)
first_branch_st4 = Dense(100, activation='relu')(first_branch_st3)
```

This sends the following error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_1973/3453405928.py in <module>
      2 first_branch_st1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28,1))(first_branch)
      3 first_branch_st2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(first_branch_st1)
----> 4 first_branch_st3 = Flatten()(first_branch_st2)
      5 first_branch_st4 = Dense(100, activation='relu')(first_branch_st3)
      6 

ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.
```

According to the question asked with the [same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67860096/got-valueerror-attempt-to-convert-a-value-none-with-an-unsupported-type-cla#) it  happens when you mix up keras and tf.keras. But i think have defined the imports accordingly, so unless there is a clash between imports or a bad definition of them i do not think that's the problem. There is another known solution?

Comment: I really could not see any errors here. Is that the whole code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: yes, there is some data adaptation code, but it's not related to this part. This is the model definition, no data introduced yet

Comment: I have the same error for Tensorflow 2.6.0 on google collab. If I downgrade to 2.5.0 it works, but only for CPU. Still can't find the solution and I am already importing only through tf.keras, not keras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only 1 bug, `Input` is not defined but still unrelated to the error mentioned. Use below:

```
first_branch= tf.keras.Input(shape=(28,28,1))
```

My advice is to please check on the latest versions of `tf` e.g. `2.4.1`.

Comment: After hours trying to find out what was wrong, reinstalling all the files to the last update, althought it was alredy at the last version. I had to delete the virtual environtment folder i had been working on and start a new folder from sratch. After that the errors dissapeared.

Comment: I give your answer as a good one to close the thread

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error that popped up when I updated to newest version of TF on google collab (2.6.0). Previously I was using 2.5 and it was running error-free.
After changing from

```
from tf.python.keras.applications.efficientnet import EfficientNetB3
```

to

```
from tf.keras.applications.efficientnet import EfficientNetB3
```

it was solved.