# Tensorflow 2.x : ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I was trying to replicate an old github repo which is in Tensorflow 1.x (exact version not mentioned). I currently have Tf 2.x and am facing issues in the code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import TimeDistributed, BatchNormalization, Flatten, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, GRU, Input, ELU
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from PIL import Image

from airsim_env import Env, ACTION
from airsim_env import get_euclidean_dist


def get_loc_score(info):
    e_dist = get_euclidean_dist(info['X'], info['Y'], info['Z'])
    score = (1.0/(1 + e_dist)) * 100

    return score


agent_name = 'ra2c'

class A2CAgent(object):
    
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size, actor_lr, critic_lr, tau,
                 gamma, lambd, entropy, horizon, load_model):
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.vel_size = 3
        self.actor_lr = actor_lr
        self.critic_lr = critic_lr
        self.tau = tau
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.lambd = lambd
        self.entropy = entropy
        self.horizon = horizon

        self.actor, self.critic = self.build_model()
        self.target_critic = self.build_model()[1]
        self.actor_update = self.build_actor_optimizer()
        self.critic_update = self.build_critic_optimizer()

        self.actor.build((None, *state_size))
        self.critic.build((None, *state_size))

        self.target_critic.build((None, *state_size))
        if load_model:
            self.load_model('./save_model/' + agent_name)

        self.target_critic.set_weights(self.critic.get_weights())

        self.states, self.actions, self.rewards = [], [], []

    def build_model(self):
        # shared network
        image = Input(shape=self.state_size)
        image_process = BatchNormalization()(image)
        image_process = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (8, 8), activation='elu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))(image_process)
        image_process = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))(image_process)
        image_process = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))(image_process)
        image_process = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))(image_process)
        image_process = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))(image_process)
        image_process = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))(image_process)
        image_process = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(8, (1, 1), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))(image_process)
        image_process = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(image_process)
        image_process = GRU(64, kernel_initializer='he_normal', use_bias=False)(image_process)
        image_process = BatchNormalization()(image_process)
        image_process = Activation('tanh')(image_process)

        # vel process
        vel = Input(shape=[self.vel_size])
        
        state_process = image_process

        # Actor
        policy = Dense(128, kernel_initializer='he_normal', use_bias=False)(state_process)
        policy = ELU()(policy)
        policy = BatchNormalization()(policy)
        policy = Dense(self.action_size, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(minval=-2e-3, maxval=2e-3))(policy)
        actor = Model(inputs=[image, vel], outputs=policy)

        # Critic
        value = Dense(128, kernel_initializer='he_normal', use_bias=False)(state_process)
        value = ELU()(value)
        value = BatchNormalization()(value)
        value = Dense(1, kernel_initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(minval=-3e-3, maxval=3e-3))(value)
        critic = Model(inputs=[image, vel], outputs=value)
        
        return actor, critic

    def build_actor_optimizer(self):
        action = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=[None, self.action_size]), shape=[None, self.action_size])
        advantages = tf.Variable(shape=[None, ])

        action.assign(tf.zeros(shape=[None, self.action_size]))

        policy = self.actor(action)

        action_prob = tf.reduce_sum(action * policy, axis=1)
        cross_entropy = tf.math.log(action_prob + 1e-6) * advantages
        cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

        entropy = tf.reduce_sum(policy * tf.math.log(policy + 1e-6), axis=1)
        entropy = tf.reduce_mean(entropy)

        loss = cross_entropy + self.entropy * entropy

        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.actor_lr)
        train = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=[action])
        return train

    def build_critic_optimizer(self):
        y = tf.Variable(shape=(None, 1))

        value = self.critic(y)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - value))

        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.critic_lr)
        train = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=[y])
        return train
```

I am facing issues in the `build_actor_optimizer()` and `build_critic_optimizer()` functions. The original code can be seen [here](https://github.com/sunghoonhong/AirsimDRL/blob/master/ra2c.py)

I found some answers on stackoverflow as well but I am not sure how to incorporate this into the code above:

[Referred stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67860096/got-valueerror-attempt-to-convert-a-value-none-with-an-unsupported-type-cla)

If there is better way to re-structure this code and make it compatible with TensorFlow 2.x,  it would help a lot. Thanks!